# 403 Forbidden error when attenpting to place base64 image in img tag

Tags: php, http-status-code-403

I selected an base64 blob image from mysql database and and attempted to insert it as a base64 image in am img tag
The console in my browser is displaying a 403 forbidden error and displaying cryptic looking characters on the viewport.

I am using XAMPP (with Apache) with Chrome browser.  How do I fix this?

Comment: Divide and conquer. Take apart every step and see where it fails. Just show a dummy page without getting anything from the datbase. Does that work? Show an image with a static blob64 image. Does that work? Do a query from your database and just output the result as test. Et cetera. At some point you'll find out at which step it fails.

Comment: Base64 is a string format. Blob is binary format. A "base64 blob" doesn't make a lot of sense. Can you please show us the generated HTML with the base64 included so we can see if it's valid or not. Seeing the code which gets the data from the database and generates the HTML might also be useful. We certainly won't be able to help you much until you clarify the situation and provide something for us to look at. It's very hard to fix invisible things. Thanks.